# Getting Mage_Core_Exception with message Invalid block type

Tags: magento-1.9

In exception.log, I am getting this error:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Bestseller' in /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('catalog/product...', Array)
#2 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(169): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/product...', NULL, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#4 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(163): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#5 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(548): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('<p>{{block type...')
#6 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php(69): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('<p>{{block type...')
#7 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Cms_Block_Block->_toHtml()
#8 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/design/frontend/default/dark-night/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(57): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/cloudpane...')
#10 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#11 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#15 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#16 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#17 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#18 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/www.example.com/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

I am not getting where I have committed a mistake and how to start debugging this case, can anyone please help!

Comment: which version are you using ?

Comment: @Manashvibirla: I am using magento 1.9.2.1

Comment: Find `catalog/product_bestseller` in your code and database.

Comment: @Rohit: Can you please elaborate a bit more!

Comment: This error coming because some where in your code or database you have this code `{{block type="catalog/product_bestseller"`

Answer (score 3):

That error is caused by the fact that you have declared a block somewhere and its associated type does not exist anymore.

In your case, Magento is looking for this file:

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Bestseller
```

But in reality, the declaration most likely look like this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_bestseller"
```

From your exception log we can be even more precise because we can see :

```
{{block type...
```

That means this block is not declared via XML but directly as a variable inside one of the following :

- CMS page
- CMS static block
- Email templates

To fix that problem I suggest:

- If you know what was this `bestseller` block for and if you know where the block declaration is located, ensure the block type is right and ensure the corresponding block class exists.
- If you don't know where this block is located you can run the following queries on your database it will help you find it:

**CMS Blocks**

```
SELECT identifier FROM `cms_block` WHERE content LIKE '%product_bestseller%';
```

**CMS Pages**

```
SELECT identifier FROM `cms_page` WHERE content LIKE '%product_bestseller%';
```

**Email Templates**

```
SELECT template_code FROM `core_email_template` WHERE template_text LIKE '%product_bestseller%';
```

Comment: I found it in CMS static block.
Where can we check for block declaration location and how to ensure block type and its corresponding block class.

Comment: @AnuragKhandelwal using my query you have found the static block identifier you can edit the block from the backend under CMS > Static blocks.

Comment: Actually the issue is that block type is correct and its corresponding class exists
Can you please suggest something

Comment: @AnuragKhandelwal what's its corresponding class ?

Comment: The corresponding class is 
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Bestseller extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract {

This is present in app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Bestseller.php

Comment: @AnuragKhandelwal where is that file located ?

Comment: Located at app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Bestseller.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37759/discussion-between-raphael-at-digital-pianism-and-anurag-khandelwal).